# Extract indexed pages from Bing

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to extract the indexed pages of a Bing Result Page.

My Code is

```
function myFunction() {
var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Aapple.com').getContentText();
var doc = XmlService.parse(html);
var html = doc.getRootElement();
var indexed_pages = getElementsByClassName(html, 'sb_count')[0];
var output = XmlService.getRawFormat().format(menu);
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(indexed_pages);
}
```

Every time it gives me the error:

> Exception: Error on line 33: The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not
>   declared.(line 3)

So in line 3 XmlService has a problem.

When I change the URL to https://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Aapple.com%2Fuk, I get another Error

> Exception: Error on line 37: The string "--" is not permitted within
>   comments. (line 3)

When I change the URL to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model it works. I guess my output is something, XmlService cannot parse. I just don't know why it can parse the Wikipedia Output but not the Bing Output.

Do you have any idea?
Thank you

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `the indexed pages of a Bing Result Page`.Can I ask you about the detail of result you expect?

Comment: When you visit e.g.: https://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Aapple.com%2Fuk there is a number on top that says "400.000 Results" The number has the class "sb_count".

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to retrieve `400.000 Results` from the URL of `https://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Aapple.com%2Fuk`. If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, it seems that the HTML from `https://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Aapple.com%2Fuk` cannot be directly parsed by XmlService. If you want to use XmlService, it is required to process the HTML data for parsing with XmlService. So in this case, as a workaround, how about directly retrieving the value of `400.000 Results` using regex?

The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Aapple.com%2Fuk').getContentText();
var res = /<span class\="sb_count">(\w.+?)<\/span>/.exec(html)[1];
Logger.log(res)
```

#### Reference:

- [exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

Comment: Wow thank you so much Tanaike! Didn't know this could be so easy :)

Comment: @SERPY Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.